# getting the row on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
AddInfo a = new AddInfo();    

int c;    
c = a.getRw();    

String sql = "select row(*) * from coproproject.table (user_id, user_lastname, user_firstname, user_mi, user_gender, user_age, bday_month, bday_date, bday_year, user_address, user_status, user_nationality, user_contact, user_email) value (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
```

i want to get the `c` (number of row in my database (coproproject.table))

i want the string value of fields from my database to appear in my text field

how would i do that ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is gibberish from start to finish

Comment: Sidenote: It's `VALUES` and not `value` --- Time for you to hit the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you're confusing yourself with **SELECT** and **INSERT**. Well, here's I think what you are looking for. **SELECT** using ***MySQLi***:

```
$YourConnection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = ($YourConnection, "SELECT * FROM coproproject");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$id=$row['user_id'];
echo "<input type='text' name='userid' value='$id'>"; /* PUT TO A TEXT FIELD THE USER_ID */

echo " ".$row['user_lastname']." ".$row['user_firstname']." ".$row['user_mi']." ".$row['user_gender']." ".$row['user_age']." ".$row['bday_month']." ".$row['bday_date']." ".$row['bday_year']." ".$row['user_address']." ".$row['user_status']." ".$row['user_nationality']." ".$row['user_contact']." ".$row['user_email']."<br>";
}

$numofRows=mysqli_num_rows($result); /* GET THE NUMBER OF FETCHED ROWS */
echo $numofRows;

?>
```

Comment: @jeanjean - No problem! Click that vote up or select my answer right if this help you solve your problem. :)

Comment: how could i retrieve the value of fields from the row that i selected ?

Comment: @jeanjean Did you unmistakenly clicked the down vote? Or there's a downvoter here?

Comment: @jeanjean What do you mean retrieve value of fields? What did you get in the code that I gave to you?

Comment: i dont know i just vote it cause it helps me

Comment: @jeanjean Did you clicked the downvote and then choose my answer as correct? Anyway, what's your current problem?

Comment: i mean . i want to get the value of the field user_id and put it on the text field

Comment: @jeanjean please see updated answer. Can you kindly upvote my answer if it helps my answer solve your problem, just to contradict the downvote earlier. Thanks

Comment: i cant it says that i need to have  reputatuins

Comment: @jeanjean I forgot. Well, see the updated answer. I edit my answer

Comment: what does this mysqli_connect means ?

Comment: It will connect to your PhpMyAdmin and select the host, the username you prefer to use, and the database you wanted to use. For more reference, you can start here and study: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp